# Create subquery in mysql with specific conditions and sort orders

Tags: mysql, subquery

in mysql I have a table with three columns - id, reference_id and order_number.
One order can be referenced to another order using the id of the main order.
Value in id is a hash value, order number is created by incremental values.

```
| id   |reference_id|order_number
|---------------------------------
| 0741 | NULL       | 000001
| 0519 | NULL       | 000002
| 3814 | 0741       | 000003
| 8163 | 0741       | 000004
| 6102 | 0519       | 000005
|---------------------------------
```

Now I want display the result ordered by order_number excepted the rows with a reference.
These rows should be displayed directly under the original order.

Expected result is:

```
| id   |reference_id|order_number
|---------------------------------
| 0741 | NULL       | 000001
| 3814 | 0741       | 000003
| 8163 | 0741       | 000004
| 0519 | NULL       | 000002
| 6102 | 0519       | 000005
|---------------------------------
```

I've done this before with two separate queries in PHP but need it now in SQL.
Any hints how to manage this? 
Is it even possible?

EDIT:
Solution for me was:

```
SELECT h1.id, h1.reference_id, h1.order_number
FROM test_order h1
LEFT JOIN test_order h2 on h2.reference_id = h1.id
ORDER BY coalesce(h2.order_number, h1.order_number), h1.order_number
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Solution was: SELECT h1.id, h1.reference_id, h1.order_number
FROM test_order h1
LEFT JOIN test_order h2 on h2.reference_id = h1.id
ORDER BY coalesce(h2.order_number, h1.order_number), h1.order_number

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
order by coalesce(reference_id, id), id
```